# Cannot get data from Java method called from Javascript in webview android

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm working on an App, where I execute a Java method when I click on a link in a webview and expect a result from that method. In that method I start another activity with `startActivityForResult` which works just fine (I have putted some logs on that activity and everythings is good), but it looks like the method doesn't return anything..

Here's my code :

**HTML : (all the includes are ok)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#run-qrscan").on("click", function(){

        var qr_data = window.WebAppInterface.startScan(); 
        // startScan is the Java method I call
        // call the function opens the activity etc.. but doesn't get any result 

        $("#display-qrresult").html(qr_data); // doesn't display anything
    });
</script>
```

**My activity : WebActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.aw_webView);

    WebAppInterface jsInterface = new WebAppInterface(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webview.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "WebAppInterface");
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

**My Javascript interface : WebAppInterface.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class WebAppInterface {

    private static Activity activity;
    public static int WEB_APP = 0;

    private static int REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE_SCAN = 1000;
    private static String qr_data = "";
    private static Intent intent;

    public WebAppInterface(Activity activity) {
        WebAppInterface.activity = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public static String startScan() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ScanActivity.class);
        WEB_APP = 1;

        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE_SCAN);

        //Wait for startActivityForResult to end -since it's asynchronous
        while(WEB_APP == 1) {}

        Log.d("qr_return", qr_data); // Doesn't display it.

        return qr_data; // Empty
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Scan QR
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE_SCAN) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                qr_data = data.getStringExtra("qr_data");
            }
        }
        WEB_APP = 0;
    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, My bad, I didn't pay attention that the class where i was calling the `startActivityForResult` was only a class and not an Activity.. So when the data was returned it wasn't returned to it..

I'm posting this code in case someone like me didn't pay attention to that.

**1- Remove the WebAppInterface.java class**

**2- WebActivity.java :**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    public static int WEB_APP = 0;

    private static int REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE_SCAN = 1000;
    private static String qr_data = "";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.aw_webView);

        WebAppInterface jsInterface = new WebAppInterface();
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "WebAppInterface");
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Scan QR
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE_SCAN) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                qr_data = data.getStringExtra("qr_data");

                Log.d("QR", qr_data);
            }
        }
        WEB_APP = 0;
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {

        WebAppInterface() {}

        @JavascriptInterface
        public  String startScan() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(WebActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
            WEB_APP = 1;

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE_SCAN);

            while(WEB_APP == 1) {}

            Log.d("qr_return", qr_data);

            return qr_data;
        }
    }
}
```